# Can a variable be recognized as an int or float or time if its stored as a varchar

Tags: php, mysql

I am in need of storing a score in a mysql field but this score could be a time,integer or float. My first way of doing this was to identify the score type and then enter it into one of three fields but if the need arises to add a new score type I dont want to have to continually add a field to the database. I remember somewhere down the line someone told me that if you store somethign as a varchar then is wont be able to be read as an integer or float or even date. My question is, can I store all three of those as one specific type but read it any way I need when taking it from the database and using it in my php code?

Comment: Yes, of course this can be done, but the bigger question is, does the need to do this indicate some fundamental problems with your data model?

Comment: I think its more for simplicity. There are different scoring types and hundreds of things that produce a score so with all the variations I just figured having one field within this table would be easier then having several and the need to introduce possible more scoring types ion in the future could arrise. I just dont want to over complicate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you could model the field as FLOAT except if you absolutely need to know about the type of variable stored. Time can be converted to an integer value by converting to timestamp. Integers are a subset of the real (floating point) numbers set actually so I guess that way you have everything covered. Floating point arithmetic can cause some issues with precision and equality testing though so be careful!

Comment: Setsuna, this is a good idea. I made sure that the time has to be a certain format and I used strtotime to convert it to a timestamp then I can store everything as a float. The purpose is to be able to pin the info onto a graph so this actually worked out. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CAST and CONVERT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/cast-functions.html) functions to convert the string datatype into another MySQL datatype such as INT, FLOAT, DECIMAL, DATE, DATETIME etc.

There are a few issues. How do you know what datatype is stored in a row? MySQL does have RegExp support but I do not recommend using it in your WHERE clauses. Store the datatype in another column.

Also, using cast functions in the where clause of your query will make them run slow. If you need to search upon/sort by the data you should use proper datatypes. Perhaps you should add one column for each datatype; and for each row, populate only the corresponding column.

Answer (score 0):

mysql will happily convert text to numbers of the appropriate type if you perform a mathematical operation on it. However, it will also convert non-numeric text to zero and perform the same operation on it, so you need to check that you're only pulling fields of the appropriate type beforehand.

[This forum post](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?60,1907,38488#msg-38488) shows how to add a regular expression condition to your query to ensure that you're only pulling fields with numeric data in them. However, I think it's probably wiser to use a separate column to indicate what type of score each record is, and use that to retrieve the appropriate ones.

I don't know how to convert text to a date (putting it through `date()` doesn't work). However, note that the mysql date format (2012-05-08 11:20:23) has the date elements in order of descending significance. If you just want to find the highest / lowest date, or sort by date, treating them as strings will work fine.